# RPIO python library running on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I tried to use the RPIO library for servo controlling using given examples.
http://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/index.html
When I execute the code I get a error

SystemError: This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!

What is the reason for this kind of error. I'm using the raspberry pi 2 with raspbian installed.  :?:

Answer (score 1):

[This issue](https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/issues/53) on Github seems to suggest that it isn't fully updated for Raspberry Pi 2 yet. A fork that has apparently fixed it is [this](https://github.com/tylerwowen/RPIO). Someone else said "deleting all RPi.GPIO files in the system and then installing from scratch the 0.5.11 version" worked for them, so you could try that.

Comment: how do i delete all the RPI.GPIO files from the system and install from scratch.

Comment: it is not yet fully updated for the pi 2 (PWM and servo methods)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it.

Use the http://raspberry-python.blogspot.ca/2015/02/raspberry-pi-2-and-rpigpio.html tutorial first.  Once this is done go to the RPIO folder on your pi and then install RPIO again except, instead of typing:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

into terminal, type:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

make sure you use python3 instead of python and this should fix the problem.